# mocha opts to look for tests in multiple directories

Tags: mocha.js, glob

I need to run tests from both `src` and `test` directories. I've added the following line to `mocha.opts`, but it doesn't help:

`"./{src,test}/**/*.spec.ts"`

Comment: Please provide the actual versus expected output, and you'll probably need to provide more of the config than just one value. That all said... why do you have tests in your src directory?? That seems... not good.

Comment: Hi. It's convenient to have specs next to actuals units/components/whatever. That's quite a regular practice I suppose. I'll update the question now. The actual problem is with glob, can't figure out how it works, as it's quite different from regexp

Comment: Actually I've just figured it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer:

`./{,+(test|src)}/**/*.spec.ts` without quotes

Answer (score 8):

You can also specify in the config files. Here is an example that looks recursively in two different directories from app root. It will look for test named `<anything>.test.js` inside any `test` directory under `mainDir1` or `mainDir2`

Example `mocha --recursive --config ./mocha-config-test.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  spec: [
    'mainDir1/**/test/**/*.test.js',
    'mainDir2/**/test/**/*.test.js',
  ],
};
```